# Html редактор CSS для сайта

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли такой редактор CSS по типу tiny mce, чтобы можно было вставить на сайт и пользователь сам мог творить что угодно средствами CSS (менять стиль таблицы, стили ссылок, и др.).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

http://ckeditor.com/  
http://habrahabr.ru/post/129262/